# what is the best way to handle large amount of data in dashboard?

Tags: angularjs

i have created a simple dashboard which have 10 to 15 widgets. so each widget are created with more than 100000 data. so there will be more than 1500000 records, how to handle it own browser.

The dashboard which i have created is just hangup.

Comment: "simple" dashboard with 1500000 records!!! man that aint that _simple_ :) btw I'm not the down-voter, but probably you gotta give more details that a one liner. I would say this is a design issue if a dashboard has lakhs of data; how would this be readable?

Comment: @Developer, widgets are bar chart, line charts, maps etc, so all widgets uses different amount of data some 100000, some 20000, some 30000.

Comment: need more details on how you are fetching the data for the charts, amount of data being fetched, chart lib used, structure of dashboard etc...

Comment: I am using rest api to fetch data from different databases, also i am using amcharts and ammaps,  i am aggregating data at frontend.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do much on the frontend, but at the backend, if you are able to change something there, I would suggest you to query only the data that is required.

When you use charts let say for showing a timeline about the sales per month you would be using group by in your sql code. This will reduce the amount of data should be significantly less because you will get only the records which are required to show instead of manipulating the result in code.

If you use a datatable handle pagination within your query, instead of pulling all data from the database, which will affect performance and will need time to load, you can pull for example the first 100 and load the next 100 records of data when the user clicks on `next page` or scroll downs (like how facebook does with their timeline). You can also consider to use an in-memory database like Redis.

Hope this helps.